# How to establish an OAuth 2.0 flow launched from Google Tag Manager side-server

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-tag-manager-server-side

I need to retrieve data from an external API every time an event is triggered on Google Tag Manager SS. The external API requires OAuth 2.0 authentication to respond to HTTP GET requests of data.

Does anyone knows how to set up this on Google Tag Manager?